# Greatest common divisor of two polynomials in $\Bbb Q[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $a$ and $b$ be two polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, where
>   $$ a = X^2+X+1 $$
>   $$ b = X - 1 $$
>
> Show that the $\gcd(a, b) = 1$.

---

I use the euclidean algorithm to compute $\gcd(a,b)$, so I have to perform a long division on $a$ with $b$. This yielded

$$ a = (X+2)(X-1)+3$$
so
$q = (X+2)$, and $r= 3$. Since my remainder is still not equal to $0$, I have to continue, but now I need to compute the $\gcd(b,r) = \gcd(X-1, 3)$.

After applying the long division again, I get a remainder of $0$ and the qoutient being equal to $\frac{1}{3}X - \frac{1}{3}$. Therefore my answer is the last non zero remainder, which is 3. Clearly I am making a mistake somewhere or missing some steps at the end of my calculation.

Comment: $1$ and $3$ are the same when it comes to gcd's. Remember that a gcd of two elements of a ring is only defined up to multiplication by a unit; for example, the gcd of the two integers $6$ and $9$ could be $3$ as well as $-3$. In practice, we usually require the gcd of two integers to be positive, the gcd of two polynomials to be monic, etc., just in order to have a unique answer; but the definition of the gcd in a ring does not define a unique element of the ring.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that reasoning clears up why 3 and 1 are equivalent in this case.

Comment: @STanja As darij, explains, the conventional *unit-normalization* of gcds in polynomial rings is to force the gcd to be *monic* by scaling by the inverse of the the leading coefficient. In particular, this normalizes gcds of degree zero to be $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculation is correct. In the rational numbers $3$ is a unit (has an inverse) so it's just as good as $1$ for the greatest common divisor.

Comment: **Because** gcds are defined only up to *unit* factors (usually one *unit-normalizes* gcds in polynomial rings over a field by making it *monic*, i.e. by scaling by the inverse of the lead coef, which normalize constant gcds to be $1)$